# How should I implement 2 different RecyclerView, taking up the same area, in a single Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I need to create the layout as shown below. What would an optimal way of implementing the adapter for this? Should I use a single RecyclerView and assign the different adapters when searchView is focused and un-focused? Or should I use 2 RecyclerViews and show one while hiding the other? [image].

I understand that this may not be a very specific question, but I didn't want to risk implementing something which would not work optimally in the end. Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: When search the back icon show, I recommend you using new Fragment instead of current Fragment, so that easy to handle back events. If you want to keep single Fragment maybe you can choose set different adapter or one adapter with 2 view type with one RecyclerView

Comment: @CôngHải Although you're right about using a 2nd fragment, I've already the functionality for pressing back while I'm in search mode, so that's okay. I think I will try switching between adapters, as that's a more straightforward solution. If it does not work well with a bigger contact database (not using the phone's native contacts), then I will consider changing it. Thank you!

Comment: I know you worry about if data list is bigger it means double memory usage when using 2 Fragment right? but I have a solution about it. When you create 2 Fragments inside single Activity, you can using share data (share ViewModel or simple way keep data list inside Activity) every Fragment with Activity host can reference to it

Comment: Ok, if simple/straightforward solution does not work, I will go for that then!